# state array keeps reordering

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of objects in my React Class component, and when I click on the class private methods, the order of the array keeps shuffling for some reason. What I am trying to do is, re-order the array by first assigning it to a variable and then setting state to another array that is just set as empty. However, even before I begin splicing the array, the console log is showing that the original array keep reordering.

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        content:[
            {
              one: 'ONE'
            },
            {
              two: 'TWO'
            },
            {
              three: 'THREE'
            }
        ],
        contentMix: null,  //The array I am going to assign the spliced array to.
     }

  someMethod () { //assume it is binded in constructor.
       /*When I click on element in render that calls this method, I console log 
      `this.state.content, and it is showing the array is out of order than what I have declared in the contructor, even though I 
       have not started splicing the arr or not even touching or changing the state 
       of this array.*/

       let arr = this.state.content
       let elementOne = this.state.content[0];
       let elementTwo = this.state.content[1];
       arr.splice(0, 2, elementTwo, elementOne)

       this.setState({ contentMix: arr})
  }
```

Comment: You are calling splice() on a state property. That method mutates the caller. You should never mutate the state directly. You should always make a copy of the state property and work with that.

Comment: Isn't that what I am doing with `let arr = this.state.content`?

Comment: In JS, assignment to an object gives a reference, not a copy. `arr` is a reference to `this.state.content`

Comment: You are mutatiing the original array. Instead create new array like this `let arr = [...this.state.content]`

Comment: No, that does not make a copy. It just assigns the reference to a state property to a variable called `arr`. If you want to reorder the array of objects in the state, you should first make a copy of that array and reorder it. I would just use slice to get all the elements but the first one; then concat that with the sliced first element, to get the first element to be at the end of the (new) array, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `splice()` on a state property. That method **mutates** the caller. You should never mutate the state directly. You should always make a **copy** of the state property and work with that.

If you want to reorder the array of objects in the state somehow, try using the `slice` method to get parts of the array you want. Then, you can combine those using `concat`. For example, to bring the first element of the list to the end of the list:

```
const firstItem = this.state.content.slice(0, 1); // this generates a single-element array
const listWithoutFirst = this.state.content.slice(1);
this.setState({ content: listWithoutFirst.concat(firstItem) });
```

Example output (I copied from a Chrome web console):

```
this.state = { content: ['a', 'b', 'c'] };
// ...
listWithoutFirst.concat(firstItem) // => ["b", "c", "a"]
```